# Extracting elements with a certain criteria from a pre existing list

Tags: functions, programming

Here I take just a random list of triples of size 10

```
 Clear[randomTriples];
 randomTriples = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3], 10];
 randomTriples 

 ={{0.933208, -0.647456, 0.356569}, {-0.770907, -0.0888585, -0.966601},{-0.241306,  0.670059, -0.0454825}, {-0.503333, 0.363352,  0.19992}, {-0.825725,-0.583199, 0.146755}, {0.756696, -0.742236, -0.531251}, {-0.120424, 0.681627, -0.313456}, {0.00651193, 0.537412, -0.232051}, {-0.636995, 0.626454, -0.658208}, {0.0108205, -0.831843, 0.519868}}
```

What if I wanted to explicitly extract ONLY the triples from the list above, that are in increasing order? So it might only be 1 of them, or maybe 6 of them, and for this example none of them are in an increasing order. BUT if I kept re-running that code or changed it to size 100 I'm sure there would be some triples that are eventually in increasing order

And I don't mean this, because this physically sorts each triple in an increasing order. This is not want I want:

```
 Sort[#, Less] & /@ randomTriples
```

I actually want to extract the lists that are already in increasing order from "randomTriples".. I think this might be harder than I think because it sounds like I need to create some sort of "IF" statement.

Comment: `Select[list, #==Sort[#]&]`>should do it.  Look at the documentation for `Select`

Comment: DeleteCases[
 Table[If[randomTriples[[j, 1]] < randomTriples[[j, 2]], 
   If[randomTriples[[j, 2]] < randomTriples[[j, 3]], 
    randomTriples[[j]]]], {j, 1, 10}], Null]  try this

Comment: @Alucard You are great.. I don't know how you did it but that does exactly what I wanted. Now I need to think through what that code is doing lol. Specifically "delete cases" and "Null"

Comment: i am just a noob, the code that jason wrote is way  better xD  i used deletecases because  table gave me the result written like   {Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, {-0.440045, -0.318807, 
  0.370605}, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, \
Null, {-0.640418, -0.40895, -0.370434}, {-0.196361, -0.0257499, 
  0.512406}, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, \
Null, Null, Null}... so i removed Null

Comment: his code works perfectly Select[randomTriples, # == Sort[#] &] altough i don't know why   lol

Comment: @Alucard What it is doing is selecting only those lists that are already sorted. So if `#` is the same as `Sort@#`, then you keep it, if not reject it.  On mobile so I can't post as an answer now

Comment: @JasonB ah yes i got it , it works on the level of the single vectors, not  on the list! thanks

Comment: Both methods work correctly, but for the sake of code simplicity JasonB has a nice solution.. Alucard your code works just fine too. Thank you both